# Current time in VMware

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, vmware-player, date-time

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 inside VMware Player. However, Ubuntu doesn't seem to check for the current time. The time is usually off when I restart the virtual machine. How can I fix this so it will check the time each time I start the VM?

Comment: It is considered as a feature to run a VM at a different time, be it past or future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confirm your server is set to synch its time with an (S)NTP server on the internet.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuTime

if it continues to be a problem you can invoke a script on boot to synch it then.

Comment: I should have clarified. I rarely reboot the VM. I just suspend it and then replay it whenever I need it. That is when the time becomes an issue.

Comment: well, you can set a script up as a cron job, running every 5 minutes or so, but since you resume without a login or boot, you can't daisy-chain it off an existing event.